# Why is the backtick key "`" in next to shift in U.S. keyboard layout in MacOS?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro, macos-bigsur

For context, I got a MacBook Pro for work (programming) in Mexico
It's updated to MacOS Big Sur 11.6, if that helps.

I tried setting the keyboard layout to U.S. (not international), as that's what I'm used to but some keys seem to have moved, even in the preview.

[image: U.S. keyboard layout preview]

What could be affecting those keys?

My current Input Sources are U.S. and Latin American.
[image: Input sources US]
[image: Input sources Latin American]

I tried removing the other layout, and toggling `Automatically switch to a document's input source` on and off, but the problem persists.

PS: The MacBook Pro has a built-in ISO keyboard, but even if I connect an ANSI magic keyboard it doesn't change

Comment: Please make sure your title matches the actual question you are asking. We cannot tell you WHY a given keyboard layout was made, but if you're asking HOW to change your layout then  we can help you with that. Use the EDIT button to fix this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you close that list, is there another input source added? If so, is the `automatically switch to a document's input source` selected? If there are two listed, I would maybe try and delete one and just use US? I looked through all of the language options and I don't even see one where the section key is in the place of the open quote. For that key on my US layout it's `option+6`

Comment: [Specify a keyboard type on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/specify-a-keyboard-type-mchlp2886/11.0/mac/11.0) see keyboard type is an option in your keyboard settings. It's not present in mine.

Comment: I believe [iso vs ansi layout](https://www.drijf.net/linuxppc/ISOvsANSI.html#:~:text=The%20ISO%20keyboard&text=Differences%20from%20the%20ANSI%20keyboard,labels%2C%20instead%20of%20text%20labels.) is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely recognising your keyboard as ISO. That's the correct place for ` on all English ISO layouts. Only the US ANSI layout has it top left, because the physical key left of z is missing on ANSI.

Comment: After your edit - double check how each keyboard responds after you press a key. Those preview images in that control panel will change after the first keypress if they "guessed wrong". Once established, each keyboard ought then to behave according to type, ANSI or ISO - so the internal will see it left of `z`, the external left of `1`. If you want to change from 'correct' recognition to a custom layout, then you need [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/)

Comment: gotcha, I'll do that, thanks!
How can I mark this as closed?